# Limit group access to 3 folders

Tags: linux, debian, permissions

I have a user in a user group, and I would like to allow that group to **ONLY** have access to 3 folders on the system.

I feel that I am missing something when reading the tutorials, because they all are saying set group permissions for chmod, but they don't say how to do it for a particular group, which is where I am getting lost. How can I set permissions for a particular group?

I created the group `untrusted` and added a user to it, how do I now limit the group to the 3 folders?

Comment: What did you try so far? That description would make it a lot easier to find a suitable solution/answer.

Comment: Using the standard authorization scheme of Linux this will be _a lot of work_ for a simple reason: users obtain access to a file or directory by three different means: a) being the owner b) being member of a group owning it or c) just being an "other" to a object which has given appropriate permission to "other". If you want this group `untrusted` to only have access to three folders this tantamount to withdrawing access to all other files/directories aquired by means b) or c). Potentially, this will affect your whole file system.

Comment: The folders I want to give access to are git Repositories, so maybe it is just possible to give access through git?